# Passing a custom function into pandas .agg()

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following aggregation in pandas:

```
summary_df = df.groupby(['provider', 'id']).agg(
    title           =('title', 'first'),
    file_size       = *custom*
).reset_index()
```

For the `file_size` I would like to use the following calculation:

```
sum([item['file_size'] for item in df if item['is_main_video'] is True])
```

How would I do the above within the `.agg()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`agg` will tagret the one column as source in your case you can create another column before `groupby`

```
df['New'] = np.where(df['is_main_video'], df['file_size'], 0)
summary_df = df.groupby(['provider', 'id']).agg(
    title           =('title', 'first'),
    file_size       = ('New', 'sum')
).reset_index()
```

Update

```
summary_df = df.assign(New = np.where(df['is_main_video'], df['file_size'], 0)).groupby(['provider', 'id']).agg(
    title           =('title', 'first'),
    file_size       = ('New', 'sum')
).reset_index()
```

Comment: I see, thanks for this. Is there another 'agg' format where you can pass the `np.where` directly into it? Or pass a named function or something?

Comment: @David542 I would recommend do above, if you would like chain the function see the update

Comment: thanks, which of the two methods would you recommend using and why? Also, with assign is there a way to make those columns temporary, so it's not passed to the resultant `df` when it returns (as for me it's only used to get the aggregated calculation and the fields themselves are worthless as stand-alone).

Comment: @David542 chaining it just makes it a "one-liner". I don't think there is any benefit besides that. Using `assign` is really helpful to make code concise and one-line, but in my opinion it's cleaner to have it on two lines in this scenario where the code after the `assign` is lengthy. It doesn't really matter though and is more about preference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Series.where` to temporarily "ignore" your file_sizes where "is_main_video" is False, then perform your groupby operation to sum the what's leftover:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "provider": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B"],
    "title": ["hello", "world", "pandas", "example", "here"],
    "is_main_video": [True, False, True, True, False],
    "file_size": [10, 12, 20, 19, 10]
})

print(df)
  provider    title  is_main_video  file_size
0        A    hello           True         10
1        A    world          False         12
2        A   pandas           True         20
3        B  example           True         19
4        B     here          False         10
```

```
aggregated_df = (df.assign(file_size=df["file_size"].where(df["is_main_video"]))
                 .groupby("provider", as_index=False)
                 .agg(
                     title=("title", "first"),
                     file_size=("file_size", "sum"))
                )

print(aggregated_df)
  provider    title  file_size
0        A    hello       30.0
1        B  example       19.0
```